# How to check if there is anything at URL?

Tags: php, url

Part of my site requires user to input URLs, but in case they type the URL incorrectly or just input a non-existent one on purpose I end up with a bad record on my database.

- E.G in Chrome if there isn't anything at a URL you get the error
  message "Oops! Google Chrome could not find fdsafadsfadsf.com". (this is the case I'm referring)

This could be solved by checking the URL to see if there is anything, I can only think of one which is loading the external URL in a PHP file and then parsing it's content. But I hope there is a method that doesn't put unneeded strain on my server.

What other ways exist to check if there is anything at a particular URL?

Comment: What about 404 error messages? http://google.com/blahblahblah should this be allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php [get_headers($url)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php), which will return false in case there isn't an answer

Comment: PHP does not use a `HEAD` request by default!  If you want to avoid wasting bandwidth with this method, you need a call to `stream_context_set_default()`, as explained in example #2 on this page:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php

Comment: I tried this: `$url = "http://hotmail.com"; if(get_headers($url)) { echo "true";}` yet if there isn't any answer I get an error message instead of false. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is the message: `Warning: get_headers() [function.get-headers]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/content/02/6945202/html/justwalkit/test.php on line 3`

Comment: turned off error reporting adding `error_reporting(0);` before it. Used a condition afterwards to test `get_headers($url)` for true or false

Answer (score 4):

I would just make a `HEAD` request.  This will work with most servers, and avoids downloading the entire page, so it is very efficient.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

All you have to do is parse the status code returned.  If it is 200, then you're good.

Example implementation with cURL here:  http://icfun.blogspot.com/2008/07/php-get-server-response-header-by.html

Comment: I tried the Curl method but it kept loading forever, I also tried the fsockopen() which was the alternative given by the blog but I get a Warning message when the site doesn't give an answer. How can I replace the error message with "no response" for example? Thanks

Comment: @Liso22, You should read the cURL documentation (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).  You need to set `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` and/or `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT`.

Answer (score 1):

if you're willing to include a tiny Flash embed you can do a crossdomain AJAX call from the client to see if anything useful is at the destination. This would alleviate any Server involvement at all.

http://jimbojw.com/wiki/index.php?title=Introduction_to_Cross-Domain_Ajax

Answer (score 1):

I would use cURL to do this, that way you can specify a timeout on it.

See the comments on: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php